# webpack thread-loader with ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have the following rule in my webpack config:

```
       {
            test: /(\.tsx?)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'thread-loader'
            },
            {
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            }]
        }
```

This results in:

```
ERROR in ./plugins/axios.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 9)
Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
```

It works fine when I remove the thread-loader.

Answer (score 14):

According to the example on [github](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/blob/master/examples/thread-loader/webpack.config.js), you need to set the `happyPackMode` option on the `ts-loader` to `true`. I've came across with the same problem you described, and this made it work.

Comment: But this stops throwing syntactic typescript errors to webpack, which is problematic

Comment: @blisher The fix is mentioned in HappyPack's [Documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#happypackmode). Note, however, that both HappyPack and ThreadLoader are deprecated in Webpack 5.